# Flex compiler omitting classes

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxmlc

I noticed that the resulting swf file of an mxmlc compilation is missing classes that are not used but still given to the compiler via the `-source-path` option.

How can this be avoided?

Also, how does the compiler find out which classes are not used?

Comment: how do you compile it? Using FlashBuilder, FDT, command line. Which other compiler arguments you have ?

Comment: using the mxmlc.jar java process. i dont have any special arguments other than the usual input files and output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the unused classes to be included, using an import on those classes should be sufficient.
Make sure you include the import in a class that is being used.

Add the compiler flag "link-report *filename*" generates a report to see what classes are included.

Comment: It is starting from the main source file.

Comment: ok, but what if i want to use some classes with reflection? or what if i compile a library which has no main source file?

Comment: libraries get compiled not with mxmlc but with compc, this accepts a "include-classes" parameter to include all classes needed.

Comment: intresting! i see compc.jar is only 476 bytes large. so i guess it is just starting mxmlc with special parameters.

Comment: You might be interested in these articles: [Using mxmlc, the application compiler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fcc.html) and [Using compc, the component compiler](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd2.html)